# Java listeners and passing arguments

Tags: java, events, event-handling, listener

I've got one listener that handles the rs232 device events and I want to pass the `String` argument to the other two listeners that are temporary. How can I do this ?

RS232 listener code:

```
 static class SerialPortReader implements SerialPortEventListener {

    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {

        if(event.isRXCHAR()){
            if(event.getEventValue() > 0){
                 try {
                     String asd= serialPort.readHexString(18);
               //asd is argument to pass to other listener
                     System.out.println(asd);
                 }
                 catch (SerialPortException ex) {
                     System.out.println(ex);
                 }
            }
        }
    }
```

And then I need a temporary listener that for example will do

```
String new = waitForPassedStringArgument();
```

or when I get the `String` the listener will change the values in `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

Are your listeners running on separate threads to the sender? If so, set up `BlockingQueue`s (one for each listener), then have your sender `offer` items to each of the queues. Each listener then retrieves items from their respective queue.

Comment: They are in the same thread. It's swing app so it will be all in EDT.

Comment: I need to do two separate get of this String:
 - User use the button to call the getString that will wait for rs232 listener output and write it to Jtextfield.
 - User use the button call to get every String that listener get and compare every string with Arraylist until the user push the stop button.